# onclick vs. event attributes of Button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React and Front End development.

I recently came across something that confused me.

Why would the following code fragment work properly:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [buttonsOnCanvas, setButtonsOnCanvas] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        event={() => {
          setButtonsOnCanvas([...buttonsOnCanvas, <Button />]);
        }}
      />
      <div className="canvas">{buttonsOnCanvas}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but not this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [buttonsOnCanvas, setButtonsOnCanvas] = useState([]);

  function handleAddButtonClick() {
    setButtonsOnCanvas([...buttonsOnCanvas, <Button />]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        onClick={() => handleAddButtonClick()}
      />
      <div className="canvas">{buttonsOnCanvas}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code for Button.js:
import React from "react";

```
export default ({ name = "Add Button", event }) => (
  <button onClick={event}>{name}</button>
);
```

The difference appears to be in onClick vs event attributes. In the event version, clicking on the  initial button instantiated within the web browser will constantly add new button instances. With onClick, nothing happens.

Comment: While not exactly what you were asking, a good rule of thumb is to never put components into state in the first place - instead, put the data needed to render the components into state, then render (and re-render) on demand when returning

Comment: Can you show the Button component ?

Comment: Here's the code for the button component
   `import React from "react"; 

    export default ({ name = "Add Button", event }) => (
      <button onClick={event}>{name}</button>
     );

I apologize if this reply is not formatted because I don't know how to do this when adding to comments.

Comment: I posted the code for Button.js in the original Question. That was the only place that I could get the formatting I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prop 'onCLick' does not exist in your Button component, that's why it does not work.
Change your Button.js

```
  export default ({ name = "Add Button", event }) => (
      <button onClick={event}>{name}</button>
  );
```

by

```
  export default ({ name = "Add Button", onClick }) => ( 
      <button onClick={onClick}>{name}</button>
  );
```

Now you ca use your Button with onClick instead of event.
Then in your App Component

```
  export default function App() {
  const [buttonsOnCanvas, setButtonsOnCanvas] = useState([]);

  function handleAddButtonClick() {
    setButtonsOnCanvas([...buttonsOnCanvas, <Button />]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        onClick={handleAddButtonClick} // Better avoid anonymous function
      />
      <div className="canvas">{buttonsOnCanvas}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: After you first asked me about the contents of the Button.js file I went off and discovered that what you just described was my main problem. It didn't hit me until then that the Button.js was a custom wrapper for the built in button comment!

Thanks for your responses J. Sometimes another pair of eyes on something does wonders!